# Bean not found from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am struggling with a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the  structure of my project using Maven :

myProject:

- moduleA  <-- has dependencies on moduleB and moduleC
- moduleB  <-- has no dependency
- moduleC  <-- has dependency on moduleB

I wrote two interfaces in moduleB, one of them is implemented in moduleB, the other one is implemented in moduleC.

Greeting interface :

```
public interface Greeting {
    WelcomeMessage greet();
}
```

Its implementation written on moduleB :

```
@Component
public class HelloWorld implements Greeting {

    private final Messages messages;

    public HelloWorld(Messages messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public WelcomeMessage greet() {
        return messages.getWelcomeMessage();
    }
}
```

Messages interface:

```
public interface Messages {
    WelcomeMessage getWelcomeMessage();
}
```

Its implementation written on moduleC :

```
@Component
public class MessagesImpl implements Messages {

    private final Mapper mapper;
    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public MessagesImpl(Mapper mapper, MessageRepository messageRepository) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public WelcomeMessage getWelcomeMessage() {
        // do something with repository and mapper
    }
}
```

My problem is Spring does not seem to use the implementation of Messages from moduleC, this error shows when I start the application :

```
**required a bean of type 'fr.mypackage.core.spi.Messages' that could not be found**
```

Also IntelliJ keeps telling me MessagesImpl is never used.

Comment: Are you using `@ComponentScan` to tell spring to go find the `@Component` annotated classes?  Do you definitely have 'module C' as a runtime (at least) dependency when running your app?

Comment: Are you including the configuration as well?    @Import({
       ModuleConfigurationFile.class })

Comment: I just used scanBasePackages in my Application file 
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "fr.mypackage")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here what I do for my libraries:

- Every library has a configuration class at top package level with `@ComponentScan`
- It can be empty or have additional beans if necessary
- Then, either the library is made an autoconfiguration with a file META-INF/spring.factories in src/main/resouces with the content:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.example.my.library.MyLibraryConfiguration
```

- Or I manually import the configuration class in my main application configuration class with `@Import(com.example.my.library.MyLibraryConfiguration)`

For a module, I recommend the autoconfiguration approach. You can `@ComponentScan` from the main application the packages of your library, but I don't recommend that, it give you less control and can be messy.

Answer (score 1):

The **module B** is getting loaded first, then **C** and finally **A**.

The **module B** contains the bean **HelloWorld** which needs a bean injected, the bean **MessagesImpl** from **module C**.

So the **MessagesImpl(module C)** cannot be injected into **HelloWorld(module B)** because it has not been created yet, hence, it is never used and the context cannot be started.

The solution would be or change the dependencies, or move the beans to another module, like **HelloWorld** on **module C** and **MessagesImpl** on **Module B**.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue while using Gradle as build tool.
In my case mongoRepository bean of module B was used in module A, so while starting up module A it was failing due to bean initialization failure.

I tried solution by adding @EntityScan and @ComponentScan with basepackage attribute but it was not worked.

Final solution was to add basePackages attribute in @EnableMongoRepositories in @Configuration class. As I was Autowiring mongorepository and that was failing.

Ex.
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycompany"})